# Getline and ifstream?

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue with ifstream and getline in conjucntion.
I have a text document:

```
1020123456
Madison Williams
90
88
79
86
90
```

And want to assign the name into a `students[0].name` where students is a `struct` of type student.
I tried using

```
inFile >> students[0].id;
getline(inFile, students[0].name);
```

`"cout << students[0].id"` yields the ID properly but .name does nothing.

What am I doing wrong here?

And `"inFile.getline(students[0].name)"` yields errors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+getline+skipping

Comment: Short answer: Don't use `>>` for input, ever.

Comment: C++ is still difficult for beginners!

Answer (score 1):

There's a `'\n'` character there after your numbers. When you `inFile >> students[0].id;` you read the number, but stop at the `'\n'` character. Then, when you `getline()`, there's that `'\n'` character left in your stream, so it reads an empty string, skips the `'\n'`, and then moves on to the next line (which is where your name is).

You need to skip the `'\n'` after you read a number and before you call `getline()`. Calling 
`inFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` will ignore what's left in `inFile` until it meets the `'\n'` character. So change it to:

```
inFile >> students[0].id;
inFile.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
getline(inFile, students[0].name);
// continue as normal...
```

Comment: Yours gave me errors but it inspired me to try `inFile.ignore();` which did exactly what I wanted it to do. Thanks.

Comment: @user1865407: Sorry, I'm an idiot. Half-way through writing my brain switched and I thought you were working with `cin` and not a `fstream`. Fixed it.